# Ansible dynamic Inventory filters for tags/labels

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to run the dynamic inventory list using Ansible

```
ansible-inventory --list -i gcp.yaml
```

```
---
plugin: gcp_compute
projects:
  - <project name>
auth_kind: serviceaccount
service_account_file: /opt/ansible/inventory/peak-equator-SA.json
filters:
        - labels|list = "ansible"
```

Getting the below error

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /opt/ansible/inventory/gcp.yaml with auto plugin: [{'message': 'Invalid value for field \'filter\': \'labels|list = "ansible"\'. Invalid
list filter expression.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid'}]
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /opt/ansible/inventory/gcp.yaml with yaml plugin: Plugin configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /opt/ansible/inventory/gcp.yaml with ini plugin: Invalid host pattern '---' supplied, '---' is normally a sign this is a YAML file.
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /opt/ansible/inventory/gcp.yaml as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {}
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can see Ansible threw warnings, this confirms your configuration is not correct. Not the root cause but the indentation under `filters`  seems wrong, it must be aligned with `- peak-equator-316104`. I advice to validate the file with yamllint and run ansible with some debug flags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After encountering this myself just now, the "filters" are not Ansible filters, but filters specific to the Google Cloud APIs: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/aggregatedList (Note: there's no `in` operator.)

I was able to use `labels.ansible != ""` as a workaround. Full dynamic inventory config for reference (GCP has the worst documentation for Ansible ever, so I know this will be useful to someone out there):

```
---
plugin: gcp_compute
projects: PROJECT_NAME_HERE

# auth using "gcloud auth application-default login"...
# you don't need a service account this way
auth_kind: application

keyed_groups:
  - key: labels
    prefix: label
  - key: zone
    prefix: zone
      
# drop any servers without an "ansible" label
# (ie. gke managed nodes)
filters:
  - labels.ansible != ""

# hostname shown in inventory
hostnames:
  - name

# ssh to hosts using private IP address
compose:
  ansible_host: networkInterfaces[0].networkIP
```

Answer (score 0):

I never use this inventory module but according the [module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_inventory.html) page, the filter should be something like that:

```yaml
filters:
    - labels = ansible
```

Comment: That doesn't help ..  Tried the same.. Labels would be map of key value pairs as a list.. will give the following error ..

`[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /opt/ansible/inventory/gcp.yaml with auto plugin: [{'message': "Internal error. Please try again or contact Google Support. (Code:
'5C5BC88674942.A8B7AC7.910374FA')", 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'backendError'}]`

Comment: Tried this way as well.

`filters:
  - labels = [{'name': 'ansible'}]`  ,  `filters:
  - labels = {{'name': 'ansible'}}` didnt help as well..

Answer (score 0):

may be try this:

```
filters:
  - labels.key=value AND labels.key=value AND labels.key=value AND labels.key=value
```